# Spring boot via gradle plugins dsl

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

Looking for spring-boot gradle plugin that I can use gradle 2+ version inside plugins DSL. I like to get rid of the buildScript definitions and  have something like

```
plugins {
    id "?" version "1.3.3.RELEASE"
}
```

https://plugins.gradle.org/ does not seem to contain spring-boot at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot's Gradle plugin isn't published to the Plugin Portal so it cannot be installed using the plugins DSL.

If you are interested in knowing why the plugin isn't published to the portal, there's an open [Spring Boot issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1567) that contains the details.

Comment: Thanks, I guess, will just have to wait some more time